# Kotlin DSL - Generic lambda with multiple receivers

Tags: kotlin, dsl

I'm creating a DSL for my project and I really want be able to use fields/methods from multiple receivers without nesting them:

For example:

```
class Foo {
    val fooField = "Foo field"
}

class Bar {
    val barField = "Bar field"
}

fun main() {

    val foo = Foo()
    val bar = Bar()

    (foo..bar) {
        println(fooField)
        println(barField)
    }

}
```

Instead of:

```
class Foo {
    val fooField = "Foo field"

    operator fun invoke(block: Foo.() -> Unit) {
        block(this)
    }
}

class Bar {
    val barField = "Bar field"

    operator fun invoke(block: Bar.() -> Unit) {
        block(this)
    }
}

fun main() {

    val foo = Foo()
    val bar = Bar()

    foo {
        bar {
            println(fooField)
            println(barField)    
        }
    }
}
```

I have thought about something like:

```
class Buzz<T1, T2>(
    val t1: T1,
    val t2: T2
) {

    operator fun invoke(function: /* T1 + T2*/ () -> Unit) { // <--- ???
        function(/* t1 + t2*/)
    }
}

operator fun <T, R> T.rangeTo(r: R): Buzz<T, R> {
    return Buzz(this, r)
}
```

But can I combine two receivers somehow without boilerplate?

Comment: How would this work? You can't have a `this` that points at two receivers.

Comment: You might really want to, but that doesn't mean you can.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that simply because a single variable can't hold reference of two objects at the same time.

But similar looking solution could be to use a pair, it could **relate*** with your problem:

```kotlin
val foo = Foo()
val bar = Bar()

Pair(foo,bar).apply {         // this: Pair<Foo, Bar>
    println(first.fooField)
    println(second.barField)
}
```

**Note*: This is just a suggestion as `it does remove boilerplate by nested lambdas`, but in other hand does not provide a solution with `lambda with multiple receivers`**

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can implement this using [delegation pattern](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/delegation.html#overriding-a-member-of-an-interface-implemented-by-delegation)

```
interface Foo {
    val fooField get() = "Foo field"
}

class FooImpl: Foo

interface Bar {
    val barField get() = "Bar field"
}

class BarImpl: Bar

class FooBar(
    val foo: Foo,
    val bar: Bar
): Foo by foo, Bar by bar {
    operator fun invoke(block: FooBar.() -> Unit) {
        block(this)
    }
}

operator fun Foo.rangeTo(bar: Bar): FooBar = FooBar(this, bar)

fun main() {
    val foo = FooImpl()
    val bar = BarImpl()

    (foo..bar) {
        println(fooField)
        println(barField)
    }

}
```